# H2 Database: expected "ALL, ANY, SOME, SELECT, FROM, WITH"

Tags: sql, h2, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am using H2 as an in memory database for unit testing our application. This query is giving the error `expected "ALL, ANY, SOME, SELECT, FROM, WITH"` for this sql query

```
SELECT CF.*, ROWNUM CASHFLOW_INDEX
FROM ( SELECT * FROM
TB_CASHFLOWS CFW WHERE CFW.CASHFLOW_DATE >= :runDate AND
CFW.CASHFLOW_TYPE <> 'ISSUE' AND CFW.ISIN = :securityCode ORDER BY
CFW.CASHFLOW_DATE,CFW.CASHFLOW_TYPE ASC ) CF
```

at the runDate location as below:

```
SELECT CF.*, ROWNUM CASHFLOW_INDEX
FROM ( SELECT * FROM
TB_CASHFLOWS CFW WHERE CFW.CASHFLOW_DATE >= :[*]RUNDATE AND
CFW.CASHFLOW_TYPE <> 'ISSUE' AND CFW.ISIN = :SECURITYCODE ORDER BY
CFW.CASHFLOW_DATE,CFW.CASHFLOW_TYPE ASC ) CF
```

But the same query is working fine in the h2 console when the parameters are given as '`2017-02-28`' and '`USD_TREASURY_28FEB`'. This query will be executed by spring jdbc template. Is this a problem with the way the parameters are passed for H2?

The java code is as below:

```
Object[] cashflowQueryArgs = new Object[] {"2017-02-28","USD_TREASURY_28FEB" };

List<Cashflow> instrumentCashflows = getJdbcTemplate().query(
    cashflowsQuery, 
    cashflowQueryArgs,
    new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Cashflow>(Cashflow.class));
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Updated.

Comment: Try to pass each parameter individually instead of an array, e.g. `query(cashflowsQuery, LocalDate.of(2017,2,28), "USD_TREASURY_28FEB", new ...)` It seems JDBC template thinks you are passing a single parameter which is an array - which matches the error message (you also shouldn't pass `Date` values as strings)

Answer (score 2):

Luckily, I found a solution. I think that H2 doesn't support named parameters. So I changed the named parameters to normal question marks and it worked!

```
SELECT CF.*, ROWNUM CASHFLOW_INDEX
FROM ( SELECT * FROM
TB_CASHFLOWS CFW WHERE CFW.CASHFLOW_DATE >= ? AND
CFW.CASHFLOW_TYPE <> 'ISSUE' AND CFW.ISIN = ? ORDER BY
CFW.CASHFLOW_DATE,CFW.CASHFLOW_TYPE ASC ) CF
```

**Updated for named parameters.**

In case for Oracle SQL, the spring jdbc template is working fine for both normal and named parameters when an array of arguments are passed to query method. But for H2, I have to use named parameter template along with SqlParameterSource. Example below:

```
MapSqlParameterSource cashflowQueryParamSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
cashflowQueryParamSource.addValue("runDate", cashflowQueryArgs[0]);
cashflowQueryParamSource.addValue("securityCode", cashflowQueryArgs[1]);

List<Cashflow> instrumentCashflows = namedJdbcTemplate.query(cashflowsQuery, cashflowQueryParamSource,
                new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Cashflow>(Cashflow.class));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No DBMS supports "named parameters" and JDBC doesn't either. Spring JDBC template manages those named parameters. I guess JDBC template thinks that you are passing a single parameter that is an array (which would explain the error message) rather than two different parameters

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name When I mentioned **In case for Oracle SQL**, It's that I didn't get the issue in case if Oracle but in case of H2 I got one.

Comment: Probably because Oracle does not support arrays and thus JdbcTemplate knows that it can't use them as a parameter